# Lspsaga.nvim throws error on hover_doc command

Tags: lua, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

It throws Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...ite\pack\packer\start\lspsaga.nvim/lua/lspsaga/hover.lua:155: attempt to call field 'set' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
...ite\pack\packer\start\lspsaga.nvim/lua/lspsaga/hover.lua:155: in function 'open_floating_preview'...

I'm using Neovim-nightly 0.9. I also tried running `:checkhealth Lspsaga` and found no errors. My `_lspsaga.lua` file look like this.

```
local status,saga = pcall(require,'lspsaga')
if (not status) then return end

saga.setup({})

local keymap = vim.keymap.set
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }

keymap('n', '<C-j>', '<cmd>Lspsaga diagnostic_jump_next<CR>', opts)
keymap('n', '<C-k>', '<cmd>Lspsaga diagnostic_jump_prev<CR>', opts)
keymap('n', 'K', '<cmd>Lspsaga hover_doc<CR>', opts)
keymap('n', 'gd', '<cmd>Lspsaga lsp_finder<CR>', opts)
keymap('i', '<C-k>', '<cmd>Lspsaga signature_help<CR>', opts)
keymap('n', 'gp', '<cmd>Lspsaga peek_definition<CR>', opts)
keymap('n', 'gr', '<cmd>Lspsaga rename<CR>', opts)
```

diagnostics and rename commands work without any issues.

Comment: I don't think you will find an answer here. You should probably rather open an issue at lspsaga: https://github.com/nvimdev/lspsaga.nvim/issues. In my experience the author is usually very responsive and tries to fix issues immediately.